# Why doesn't my scanner work with 12.10 while it worked with 12.04?

Tags: 12.10, hp, scanner

I can not scan with Ubuntu 12.10. In Ubuntu 12.04 I could scan with the same hardware.

```
carsten@CARSTEN-A55VD:~$ simple-scan -d
[+0,00s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:582: Starting Simple Scan 3.6.0, PID=4659
[+0,00s] DEBUG: Connecting to session manager
[+0,04s] DEBUG: ui.vala:1404: Restoring window to 999x601 pixels
[+0,04s] DEBUG: ui.vala:1409: Restoring window to maximized
[+0,07s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1378: sane_init () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+0,07s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1384: SANE version 1.0.23
[+0,07s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1445: Requesting redetection of scan devices
[+0,07s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:753: Processing request
[+2,62s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:310: Requesting scan at 150 dpi from device '(null)'
[+2,62s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1491: Scanner.scan ("(null)", dpi=150,     scan_mode=ScanMode.GRAY, depth=2, type=ScanType.SINGLE, paper_width=0, paper_height=0)
[+2,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:334: sane_get_devices () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+2,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:346: Device: name="plustek:libusb:003:005" vendor="Hewlett-Packard" model="Scanjet 2200c" type="flatbed scanner"
[+2,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:753: Processing request
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:814: sane_open ("plustek:libusb:003:005") -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (0)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 0: title='Number of options' type=int size=4 cap=,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Read-only option that specifies how many options a specific devices supports.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (1)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 1: name='(null)' title='Scan Mode' type=group size=4
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: 
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (2)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 2: name='mode' title='Scan mode' type=string size=8 values=["Lineart", "Gray", "Color"] cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Selects the scan mode (e.g., lineart, monochrome, or color).
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (3)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 3: name='depth' title='Bit depth' type=int size=4 unit=bits values=[8, 14] cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Number of bits per sample, typical values are 1 for "line-art" and 8 for multibit scans.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (4)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 4: name='source' title='Scan source' type=string size=13 values=["Normal", "Transparency", "Negative"] cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Selects the scan source (such as a document-feeder).
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (5)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 5: name='resolution' title='Scan resolution' type=int size=4 unit=dpi min=50, max=1200, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Sets the resolution of the scanned image.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (6)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 6: name='preview' title='Preview' type=bool size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Request a preview-quality scan.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (7)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 7: name='(null)' title='Geometry' type=group size=4 cap=,advanced
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: 
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (8)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 8: name='tl-x' title='Top-left x' type=fixed size=4 unit=mm min=0,000000, max=215,000000, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Top-left x position of scan area.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (9)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 9: name='tl-y' title='Top-left y' type=fixed size=4 unit=mm min=0,000000, max=297,000000, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Top-left y position of scan area.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (10)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 10: name='br-x' title='Bottom-right x' type=fixed size=4 unit=mm min=0,000000, max=215,000000, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Bottom-right x position of scan area.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (11)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 11: name='br-y' title='Bottom-right y' type=fixed size=4 unit=mm min=0,000000, max=297,000000, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Bottom-right y position of scan area.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (12)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 12: name='(null)' title='Enhancement' type=group size=4
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: 
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (13)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 13: name='brightness' title='Brightness' type=fixed size=4 unit=percent min=-100,000000, max=100,000000, quant=65536 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Controls the brightness of the acquired image.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (14)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 14: name='contrast' title='Contrast' type=fixed size=4 unit=percent min=-100,000000, max=100,000000, quant=65536 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Controls the contrast of the acquired image.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (15)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 15: name='custom-gamma' title='Use custom gamma table' type=bool size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Determines whether a builtin or a custom gamma-table should be used.
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (16)
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 16: name='gamma-table' title='Image intensity' type=int size=16384 min=0, max=255, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Gamma-correction table.  In color mode this option equally affects the red, green, and blue channels simultaneously (i.e., it is an intensity gamma table).
[+32,68s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (17)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 17: name='red-gamma-table' title='Red intensity' type=int size=16384 min=0, max=255, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Gamma-correction table for the red band.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (18)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 18: name='green-gamma-table' title='Green intensity' type=int size=16384 min=0, max=255, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Gamma-correction table for the green band.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (19)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 19: name='blue-gamma-table' title='Blue intensity' type=int size=16384 min=0, max=255, quant=0 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Gamma-correction table for the blue band.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (20)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 20: name='(null)' title='Device-Settings' type=group size=4
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: 
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (21)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 21: name='lamp-switch' title='Lampswitch' type=bool size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Manually switching the lamp(s).
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (22)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 22: name='lampoff-time' title='Lampoff-time' type=int size=4 min=0, max=999, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Lampoff-time in seconds.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (23)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 23: name='lamp-off-at-exit' title='Lamp off at exit' type=bool size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Turn off lamp when program exits
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (24)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 24: name='warmup-time' title='Warmup-time' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=999, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Warmup-time in seconds.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (25)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 25: name='lamp-off-during-dcal' title='Lamp off during dark calibration' type=bool size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Always switches lamp off when doing dark calibration.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (26)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 26: name='calibration-cache' title='Calibration data cache' type=bool size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Enables or disables calibration data cache.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (27)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 27: name='speedup-switch' title='Speedup sensor' type=bool size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Enables or disables speeding up sensor movement.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (28)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 28: name='calibrate' title='Calibrate' type=button size=4 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,automatic,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Performs calibration
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (29)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 29: name='(null)' title='Analog frontend' type=group size=4 cap=,advanced
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: 
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (30)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 30: name='red-gain' title='Red gain' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=63, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Red gain value of the AFE
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (31)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 31: name='green-gain' title='Green gain' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=63, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Green gain value of the AFE
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (32)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 32: name='blue-gain' title='Blue gain' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=63, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Blue gain value of the AFE
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (33)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 33: name='red-offset' title='Red offset' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=63, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Red offset value of the AFE
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (34)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 34: name='green-offset' title='Green offset' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=63, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Green offset value of the AFE
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (35)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 35: name='blue-offset' title='Blue offset' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=63, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Blue offset value of the AFE
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (36)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 36: name='redlamp-off' title='Red lamp off' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=16363, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Defines red lamp off parameter
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (37)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 37: name='greenlamp-off' title='Green lamp off' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=16363, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Defines green lamp off parameter
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (38)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 38: name='bluelamp-off' title='Blue lamp off' type=int size=4 min=-1, max=16363, quant=1 cap=,soft-select,soft-detect,inactive
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: Defines blue lamp off parameter
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (39)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 39: name='(null)' title='Buttons' type=group size=4 cap=,advanced
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: 
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (40)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 40: name='button 0' title='Scanner button 0' type=bool size=4 cap=,hard-select,soft-detect,advanced
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: This option reflects the status of the scanner buttons.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (41)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 41: name='button 1' title='Scanner button 1' type=bool size=4 cap=,hard-select,soft-detect,advanced
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: This option reflects the status of the scanner buttons.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (42)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 42: name='button 2' title='Scanner button 2' type=bool size=4 cap=,hard-select,soft-detect,inactive,advanced
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: This option reflects the status of the scanner buttons.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (43)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 43: name='button 3' title='Scanner button 3' type=bool size=4 cap=,hard-select,soft-detect,inactive,advanced
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: This option reflects the status of the scanner buttons.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (44)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:685: Option 44: name='button 4' title='Scanner button 4' type=bool size=4 cap=,hard-select,soft-detect,inactive,advanced
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:688:   Description: This option reflects the status of the scanner buttons.
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:835: sane_get_option_descriptor (45)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:497: sane_control_option (2, SANE_ACTION_SET_VALUE, "Gray") -> (SANE_STATUS_GOOD, "Gray")
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:439: sane_control_option (5, SANE_ACTION_SET_VALUE, 150) -> (SANE_STATUS_GOOD, 150)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:439: sane_control_option (3, SANE_ACTION_SET_VALUE, 2) -> (SANE_STATUS_GOOD, 8)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:479: sane_control_option (10, SANE_ACTION_SET_VALUE, 215,000000) -> (SANE_STATUS_GOOD, 215,000000)
[+32,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:479: sane_control_option (11, SANE_ACTION_SET_VALUE, 297,000000) -> (SANE_STATUS_GOOD, 297,000000)
[+62,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1141: sane_start (page=0, pass=0) -> SANE_STATUS_IO_ERROR
[+62,69s] WARNING: scanner.vala:1148: Unable to start device: Error during device I/O
[+62,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:715: sane_cancel ()
[+62,69s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:718: sane_close ()
[+70,21s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1515: Stopping scan thread
[+70,21s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:753: Processing request
[+70,21s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1523: sane_exit ()
```

How do I resolve the issue?

```
carsten@CARSTEN-A55VD:~$ sane-find-scanner

# sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
# result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
# scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

# No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
# you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient    permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 002:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x0605 [HP ScanJet 2200C]) at libusb:003:006
could not open USB device 0x0781/0x5571 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x045e/0x0745 at 003:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f2/0xb354 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
# Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
# SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

# Not checking for parallel port scanners.

# Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
# can't be detected by this program.

# You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
# found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
# necessary.
carsten@CARSTEN-A55VD:~$ scanimage -L
device `plustek:libusb:003:006' is a Hewlett-Packard Scanjet 2200c flatbed scanner
carsten@CARSTEN-A55VD:~$
```

The Scanner is a Hewlett-Packard Scanjet 2200c.

Comment: What are the results of `sane-find-scanner` and `scanimage -L`? And is there a reason for not telling us brand/make/model of your scanner? (seems important information to me).

Comment: i have edit my ask

Answer (score 1):

Problem you face is this: `No SCSI scanners found`.

The answer is given too: `If you expected something different, make sure that you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.`

Looks like you need to install a backend. 
This http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sane-plustek.5.html  states you can use `sane-plustek` so install that one.

```
Vendor Hewlett-Packard - ID: 0x03F0
   ----------------------------------------------------------
   USB Model:         ASIC:  Properties:              Prod-ID
   ----------------------------------------------------------
   ScanJet 2100C      LM9831  600x1200dpi 42bit 512Kb 0x0505
   ScanJet 2200C      LM9832  600x1200dpi 42bit 512Kb 0x0605
```

---

Oh and ... if you look at the link I posted: looks like 12.04 did have that package and 12.10 has not been updated (it shows the 12.04 package in the manual). So this answers why it does work on 12.04 and not in 12.10

Comment: thank you....now i can buy a new scanner :(. I do not get enough experience to all.

Comment: I do not understand this comment @user133449 Just install the `sane-plustek` package and it should work.

Comment: Why i can install sane-plustek? Ubuntu 12.10 i find no package. And when i download the file....where copy?

Comment: Install the 12.04 package debian installer from the link I postes. USC will handle everything else.